# Best way to store table (spreadsheet) data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

To store table like data in Mongodb when the table is fixed size, arrays could work. But when the table can grow (like a spreadsheet) or even be more flexible (the number animals of a species at a zoo, where both the species and zoo can be extended) this won't work. So I'm thinking more like:

```
{
    "name": "spreadsheet example",
    "cells": [
        {
            "row": 1,
            "col": 1,
            "val": 4
        },
        {
            "row": 1,
            "col": 2,
            "val": 9
        },
        {
            "row": 1,
            "col": 3,
            "val": "a1+a2"
        }
    ]
}
```

This would work, and even be efficient for sparse table, but when rendering the table to HTML it would require a lookup for every cell, or building some intermediate data structure. Also, this way a single cell can be updated using the '$' positional operator in an update, but if we have multiple tabs there is a problem as the '$' cannot be nested...

Is there a better way to store this information in mongodb? I considerd using the row/col names as field names, but that results in dynamic field names, also probably not the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

things that worry me with your approach are:

- the [The maximum BSON document size](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/limits/) which is 16 megabytes, that
  means you can't store a big spreadsheet in a single document.
- accessing array items with '$' operator is a little complicated
- it has a lot of storage overhead (keeping row/column info for each and every cell.
  I would rather use a more natural schema as:

  {_id: row_number, col_a: value_of_column_A, .... , col_n: value_of_column_n}

and dedicate one collection for one spreadsheet or:

```
{_id: spreadsheet_name, row: row_number, col_a:value_of_column_A, .... , col_n:value_of_column_n}
```

if you want to accommodate more than one spreadsheet per collection.
This way you can also use meaningful header names instead of column numbers.
I wrote [an open sourced module in python](http://miloncdn.appspot.com/docs/mongoUtils/mongoUtils.importsExports.html) that auto-imports a spreadsheet or a complete workbook via xlrd to mongoDB, using above schema.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do this. 
Mongodb is based on [documents](https://www.mongodb.org/about/introduction/), and has pros and cons.

In your case you should use a **mysql** database or any other database oriented to **tables**, as you need to store those spreadsheet.

Comment: Would add explanation in pro and con section? Your weblink just led to the main MongoDB webpage.